# Regex - How to find all value with a specific key from json format in Python

Tags: python, regex

I want to find all the link for the large keyword from the following string `"large": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41mHHkM79UL._AC_.jpg"`
I have looked some other posts and on some other websites too but none of my attempts seem to work.

The whole string is like this:

```
"""
P.when('A').register("ImageBlockATF", function(A){
    var data = {
    'colorImages': { 'initial': [
                {
                    "hiRes": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81zzDnLOXmL._AC_SL1500_.jpg",
                    "thumb": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41mHHkM79UL._AC_US40_.jpg",
                    "large": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41mHHkM79UL._AC_.jpg",
                    "main": {
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81zzDnLOXmL._AC_SY355_.jpg": [
                            355,
                            355
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81zzDnLOXmL._AC_SY450_.jpg": [
                            450,
                            450
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81zzDnLOXmL._AC_SX425_.jpg": [
                            425,
                            425
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81zzDnLOXmL._AC_SX466_.jpg": [
                            466,
                            466
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81zzDnLOXmL._AC_SX522_.jpg": [
                            522,
                            522
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81zzDnLOXmL._AC_SX569_.jpg": [
                            569,
                            569
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81zzDnLOXmL._AC_SX679_.jpg": [
                            679,
                            679
                        ]
                    },
                    "variant": "MAIN",
                    "lowRes": null,
                    "shoppableScene": null
                },
                {
                    "hiRes": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91EX6CXAetL._AC_SL1500_.jpg",
                    "thumb": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/51Xf2DrAufL._AC_US40_.jpg",
                    "large": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/51Xf2DrAufL._AC_.jpg",
                    "main": {
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91EX6CXAetL._AC_SY355_.jpg": [
                            355,
                            355
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91EX6CXAetL._AC_SY450_.jpg": [
                            450,
                            450
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91EX6CXAetL._AC_SX425_.jpg": [
                            425,
                            425
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91EX6CXAetL._AC_SX466_.jpg": [
                            466,
                            466
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91EX6CXAetL._AC_SX522_.jpg": [
                            522,
                            522
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91EX6CXAetL._AC_SX569_.jpg": [
                            569,
                            569
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91EX6CXAetL._AC_SX679_.jpg": [
                            679,
                            679
                        ]
                    },
                    "variant": "PT01",
                    "lowRes": null,
                    "shoppableScene": null
                },
                {
                    "hiRes": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91HB5N1ArxL._AC_SL1500_.jpg",
                    "thumb": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/517s1wNq+BL._AC_US40_.jpg",
                    "large": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/517s1wNq+BL._AC_.jpg",
                    "main": {
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91HB5N1ArxL._AC_SY355_.jpg": [
                            355,
                            355
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91HB5N1ArxL._AC_SY450_.jpg": [
                            450,
                            450
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91HB5N1ArxL._AC_SX425_.jpg": [
                            425,
                            425
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91HB5N1ArxL._AC_SX466_.jpg": [
                            466,
                            466
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91HB5N1ArxL._AC_SX522_.jpg": [
                            522,
                            522
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91HB5N1ArxL._AC_SX569_.jpg": [
                            569,
                            569
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91HB5N1ArxL._AC_SX679_.jpg": [
                            679,
                            679
                        ]
                    },
                    "variant": "PT02",
                    "lowRes": null,
                    "shoppableScene": null
                },
                {
                    "hiRes": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81u4gn4By+L._AC_SL1500_.jpg",
                    "thumb": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/417qX3hFhSL._AC_US40_.jpg",
                    "large": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/417qX3hFhSL._AC_.jpg",
                    "main": {
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81u4gn4By+L._AC_SY355_.jpg": [
                            355,
                            355
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81u4gn4By+L._AC_SY450_.jpg": [
                            450,
                            450
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81u4gn4By+L._AC_SX425_.jpg": [
                            425,
                            425
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81u4gn4By+L._AC_SX466_.jpg": [
                            466,
                            466
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81u4gn4By+L._AC_SX522_.jpg": [
                            522,
                            522
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81u4gn4By+L._AC_SX569_.jpg": [
                            569,
                            569
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81u4gn4By+L._AC_SX679_.jpg": [
                            679,
                            679
                        ]
                    },
                    "variant": "PT03",
                    "lowRes": null,
                    "shoppableScene": null
                },
                {
                    "hiRes": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/8144z2T8HVL._AC_SL1500_.jpg",
                    "thumb": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/410iFp5eaDL._AC_US40_.jpg",
                    "large": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/410iFp5eaDL._AC_.jpg",
                    "main": {
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/8144z2T8HVL._AC_SY355_.jpg": [
                            355,
                            355
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/8144z2T8HVL._AC_SY450_.jpg": [
                            450,
                            450
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/8144z2T8HVL._AC_SX425_.jpg": [
                            425,
                            425
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/8144z2T8HVL._AC_SX466_.jpg": [
                            466,
                            466
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/8144z2T8HVL._AC_SX522_.jpg": [
                            522,
                            522
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/8144z2T8HVL._AC_SX569_.jpg": [
                            569,
                            569
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/8144z2T8HVL._AC_SX679_.jpg": [
                            679,
                            679
                        ]
                    },
                    "variant": "PT04",
                    "lowRes": null,
                    "shoppableScene": null
                },
                {
                    "hiRes": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/710ixzIU0qL._AC_SL1500_.jpg",
                    "thumb": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41CfvwfIbzL._AC_US40_.jpg",
                    "large": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41CfvwfIbzL._AC_.jpg",
                    "main": {
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/710ixzIU0qL._AC_SY355_.jpg": [
                            355,
                            355
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/710ixzIU0qL._AC_SY450_.jpg": [
                            450,
                            450
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/710ixzIU0qL._AC_SX425_.jpg": [
                            425,
                            425
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/710ixzIU0qL._AC_SX466_.jpg": [
                            466,
                            466
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/710ixzIU0qL._AC_SX522_.jpg": [
                            522,
                            522
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/710ixzIU0qL._AC_SX569_.jpg": [
                            569,
                            569
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/710ixzIU0qL._AC_SX679_.jpg": [
                            679,
                            679
                        ]
                    },
                    "variant": "PT05",
                    "lowRes": null,
                    "shoppableScene": null
                },
                {
                    "hiRes": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91JLoX-b-vL._AC_SL1500_.jpg",
                    "thumb": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/5164gjcgHIL._AC_US40_.jpg",
                    "large": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/5164gjcgHIL._AC_.jpg",
                    "main": {
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91JLoX-b-vL._AC_SY355_.jpg": [
                            355,
                            355
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91JLoX-b-vL._AC_SY450_.jpg": [
                            450,
                            450
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91JLoX-b-vL._AC_SX425_.jpg": [
                            425,
                            425
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91JLoX-b-vL._AC_SX466_.jpg": [
                            466,
                            466
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91JLoX-b-vL._AC_SX522_.jpg": [
                            522,
                            522
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91JLoX-b-vL._AC_SX569_.jpg": [
                            569,
                            569
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91JLoX-b-vL._AC_SX679_.jpg": [
                            679,
                            679
                        ]
                    },
                    "variant": "PT06",
                    "lowRes": null,
                    "shoppableScene": null
                },
                {
                    "hiRes": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91W7gb7CjWL._AC_SL1500_.jpg",
                    "thumb": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/61VgpB5DRyL._AC_US40_.jpg",
                    "large": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/61VgpB5DRyL._AC_.jpg",
                    "main": {
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91W7gb7CjWL._AC_SY355_.jpg": [
                            355,
                            355
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91W7gb7CjWL._AC_SY450_.jpg": [
                            450,
                            450
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91W7gb7CjWL._AC_SX425_.jpg": [
                            425,
                            425
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91W7gb7CjWL._AC_SX466_.jpg": [
                            466,
                            466
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91W7gb7CjWL._AC_SX522_.jpg": [
                            522,
                            522
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91W7gb7CjWL._AC_SX569_.jpg": [
                            569,
                            569
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91W7gb7CjWL._AC_SX679_.jpg": [
                            679,
                            679
                        ]
                    },
                    "variant": "PT07",
                    "lowRes": null,
                    "shoppableScene": null
                }
            ]
        },
    'colorToAsin': {'initial': {}
        },
    'holderRatio': 1.0,
    'holderMaxHeight': 700,
    'heroImage': {'initial': []
        },
    'heroVideo': {'initial': []
        },
    'spin360ColorData': {'initial': {}
        },
    'spin360ColorEnabled': {'initial': 0
        },
    'spin360ConfigEnabled': true,
    'spin360LazyLoadEnabled': false,
    'showroomEnabled': false,
    'showroomViewModel': {'initial': {}
        },
    'playVideoInImmersiveView': true,
    'useTabbedImmersiveView': true,
    'totalVideoCount':'0',
    'videoIngressATFSlateThumbURL':'',
    'mediaTypeCount':'0',
    'atfEnhancedHoverOverlay' : true,
    'winningAsin': 'B0033990ZQ',
    'weblabs' : {},
    'aibExp3Layout' : 1,
    'aibRuleName' : 'frank-powered',
    'acEnabled' : true,
    'dp60VideoPosition': 0,
    'dp60VariantList': '',
    'dp60VideoThumb': '',
    'dp60MainImage': 'https: //m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81zzDnLOXmL._AC_SY355_.jpg',
    'imageBlockRenderingStartTime': Date.now(),
    'shoppableSceneWeblabEnabled': false,
    
    'airyConfig' :A.$.parseJSON('{
            "jsUrl": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/vap/video/airy2/prod/2.0.1460.0/js/airy.skin._CB485981857_.js",
            "cssUrl": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/vap/video/airy2/prod/2.0.1460.0/css/beacon._CB485971591_.css",
            "swfUrl": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/vap/video/airy2/prod/2.0.1460.0/flash/AiryBasicRenderer._CB485925577_.swf",
            "foresterMetadataParams": {
                "marketplaceId": "ATVPDKIKX0DER",
                "method": "Sports.ImageBlock",
                "requestId": "CNWR29DQN7HDJNZBH41R",
                "session": "142-4118660-8915941",
                "client": "Dpx"
            }
        }')
    };
    A.trigger('P.AboveTheFold'); // trigger ATF event.
    return data;
});
"""
```

is it possible with regex? I am using python. Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use this pattern: `(?<=\"large\":\s\")[^"]+`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this pattern: `(?<=\"large\":\s\")[^\"]+`

This code will give you all links with key `"large"`:

```
import re

pattern = r"(?<=\"large\":\s\")[^\"]+"
text = """
Your huge string
"""

print(re.findall(pattern, text))
```

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=)` Starting matches from where that pattern inside it is in behind position.
- `\"large\":\s\"` Match exactly with `"large": "`
- `[^\"]+` Match one or more anything except for double quotation.

Comment: @IbtsamCh You do not need a lookbehind though, `pattern = r'"large":\s*"([^"]+)'` will do.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to find this exact keyword in the string, which is what you asked:

```
"large": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41mHHkM79UL._AC_.jpg"
```

I have outlined three ways to do this. The first method uses regex without an r-string, which disables the special regex characters (meaning you will not be able to expand upon it later).

The second method uses a standard r-string and escapes the special characters in your keyword (otherwise the `/` and `.` will mess up your search).

The third method doesn't use regex at all, and is probably the best solution if you just want to find a string in another string.

```
import re

test_string = """
P.when('A').register("ImageBlockATF", function(A){
    var data = {
    'colorImages': { 'initial': [
                {
                    "hiRes": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81zzDnLOXmL._AC_SL1500_.jpg",
                    "thumb": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41mHHkM79UL._AC_US40_.jpg",
                    "large": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41mHHkM79UL._AC_.jpg",
                    "main": {
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81zzDnLOXmL._AC_SY355_.jpg": [
                            355,
                            355
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81zzDnLOXmL._AC_SY450_.jpg": [
                            450,
                            450
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81zzDnLOXmL._AC_SX425_.jpg": [
                            425,
                            425
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81zzDnLOXmL._AC_SX466_.jpg": [
                            466,
                            466
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81zzDnLOXmL._AC_SX522_.jpg": [
                            522,
                            522
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81zzDnLOXmL._AC_SX569_.jpg": [
                            569,
                            569
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81zzDnLOXmL._AC_SX679_.jpg": [
                            679,
                            679
                        ]
                    },
                    "variant": "MAIN",
                    "lowRes": null,
                    "shoppableScene": null
                },
                {
                    "hiRes": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91EX6CXAetL._AC_SL1500_.jpg",
                    "thumb": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/51Xf2DrAufL._AC_US40_.jpg",
                    "large": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/51Xf2DrAufL._AC_.jpg",
                    "main": {
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91EX6CXAetL._AC_SY355_.jpg": [
                            355,
                            355
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91EX6CXAetL._AC_SY450_.jpg": [
                            450,
                            450
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91EX6CXAetL._AC_SX425_.jpg": [
                            425,
                            425
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91EX6CXAetL._AC_SX466_.jpg": [
                            466,
                            466
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91EX6CXAetL._AC_SX522_.jpg": [
                            522,
                            522
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91EX6CXAetL._AC_SX569_.jpg": [
                            569,
                            569
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91EX6CXAetL._AC_SX679_.jpg": [
                            679,
                            679
                        ]
                    },
                    "variant": "PT01",
                    "lowRes": null,
                    "shoppableScene": null
                },
                {
                    "hiRes": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91HB5N1ArxL._AC_SL1500_.jpg",
                    "thumb": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/517s1wNq+BL._AC_US40_.jpg",
                    "large": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/517s1wNq+BL._AC_.jpg",
                    "main": {
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91HB5N1ArxL._AC_SY355_.jpg": [
                            355,
                            355
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91HB5N1ArxL._AC_SY450_.jpg": [
                            450,
                            450
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91HB5N1ArxL._AC_SX425_.jpg": [
                            425,
                            425
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91HB5N1ArxL._AC_SX466_.jpg": [
                            466,
                            466
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91HB5N1ArxL._AC_SX522_.jpg": [
                            522,
                            522
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91HB5N1ArxL._AC_SX569_.jpg": [
                            569,
                            569
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91HB5N1ArxL._AC_SX679_.jpg": [
                            679,
                            679
                        ]
                    },
                    "variant": "PT02",
                    "lowRes": null,
                    "shoppableScene": null
                },
                {
                    "hiRes": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81u4gn4By+L._AC_SL1500_.jpg",
                    "thumb": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/417qX3hFhSL._AC_US40_.jpg",
                    "large": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/417qX3hFhSL._AC_.jpg",
                    "main": {
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81u4gn4By+L._AC_SY355_.jpg": [
                            355,
                            355
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81u4gn4By+L._AC_SY450_.jpg": [
                            450,
                            450
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81u4gn4By+L._AC_SX425_.jpg": [
                            425,
                            425
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81u4gn4By+L._AC_SX466_.jpg": [
                            466,
                            466
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81u4gn4By+L._AC_SX522_.jpg": [
                            522,
                            522
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81u4gn4By+L._AC_SX569_.jpg": [
                            569,
                            569
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81u4gn4By+L._AC_SX679_.jpg": [
                            679,
                            679
                        ]
                    },
                    "variant": "PT03",
                    "lowRes": null,
                    "shoppableScene": null
                },
                {
                    "hiRes": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/8144z2T8HVL._AC_SL1500_.jpg",
                    "thumb": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/410iFp5eaDL._AC_US40_.jpg",
                    "large": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/410iFp5eaDL._AC_.jpg",
                    "main": {
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/8144z2T8HVL._AC_SY355_.jpg": [
                            355,
                            355
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/8144z2T8HVL._AC_SY450_.jpg": [
                            450,
                            450
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/8144z2T8HVL._AC_SX425_.jpg": [
                            425,
                            425
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/8144z2T8HVL._AC_SX466_.jpg": [
                            466,
                            466
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/8144z2T8HVL._AC_SX522_.jpg": [
                            522,
                            522
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/8144z2T8HVL._AC_SX569_.jpg": [
                            569,
                            569
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/8144z2T8HVL._AC_SX679_.jpg": [
                            679,
                            679
                        ]
                    },
                    "variant": "PT04",
                    "lowRes": null,
                    "shoppableScene": null
                },
                {
                    "hiRes": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/710ixzIU0qL._AC_SL1500_.jpg",
                    "thumb": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41CfvwfIbzL._AC_US40_.jpg",
                    "large": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41CfvwfIbzL._AC_.jpg",
                    "main": {
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/710ixzIU0qL._AC_SY355_.jpg": [
                            355,
                            355
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/710ixzIU0qL._AC_SY450_.jpg": [
                            450,
                            450
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/710ixzIU0qL._AC_SX425_.jpg": [
                            425,
                            425
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/710ixzIU0qL._AC_SX466_.jpg": [
                            466,
                            466
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/710ixzIU0qL._AC_SX522_.jpg": [
                            522,
                            522
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/710ixzIU0qL._AC_SX569_.jpg": [
                            569,
                            569
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/710ixzIU0qL._AC_SX679_.jpg": [
                            679,
                            679
                        ]
                    },
                    "variant": "PT05",
                    "lowRes": null,
                    "shoppableScene": null
                },
                {
                    "hiRes": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91JLoX-b-vL._AC_SL1500_.jpg",
                    "thumb": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/5164gjcgHIL._AC_US40_.jpg",
                    "large": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/5164gjcgHIL._AC_.jpg",
                    "main": {
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91JLoX-b-vL._AC_SY355_.jpg": [
                            355,
                            355
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91JLoX-b-vL._AC_SY450_.jpg": [
                            450,
                            450
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91JLoX-b-vL._AC_SX425_.jpg": [
                            425,
                            425
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91JLoX-b-vL._AC_SX466_.jpg": [
                            466,
                            466
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91JLoX-b-vL._AC_SX522_.jpg": [
                            522,
                            522
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91JLoX-b-vL._AC_SX569_.jpg": [
                            569,
                            569
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91JLoX-b-vL._AC_SX679_.jpg": [
                            679,
                            679
                        ]
                    },
                    "variant": "PT06",
                    "lowRes": null,
                    "shoppableScene": null
                },
                {
                    "hiRes": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91W7gb7CjWL._AC_SL1500_.jpg",
                    "thumb": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/61VgpB5DRyL._AC_US40_.jpg",
                    "large": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/61VgpB5DRyL._AC_.jpg",
                    "main": {
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91W7gb7CjWL._AC_SY355_.jpg": [
                            355,
                            355
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91W7gb7CjWL._AC_SY450_.jpg": [
                            450,
                            450
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91W7gb7CjWL._AC_SX425_.jpg": [
                            425,
                            425
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91W7gb7CjWL._AC_SX466_.jpg": [
                            466,
                            466
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91W7gb7CjWL._AC_SX522_.jpg": [
                            522,
                            522
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91W7gb7CjWL._AC_SX569_.jpg": [
                            569,
                            569
                        ],
                        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91W7gb7CjWL._AC_SX679_.jpg": [
                            679,
                            679
                        ]
                    },
                    "variant": "PT07",
                    "lowRes": null,
                    "shoppableScene": null
                }
            ]
        },
    'colorToAsin': {'initial': {}
        },
    'holderRatio': 1.0,
    'holderMaxHeight': 700,
    'heroImage': {'initial': []
        },
    'heroVideo': {'initial': []
        },
    'spin360ColorData': {'initial': {}
        },
    'spin360ColorEnabled': {'initial': 0
        },
    'spin360ConfigEnabled': true,
    'spin360LazyLoadEnabled': false,
    'showroomEnabled': false,
    'showroomViewModel': {'initial': {}
        },
    'playVideoInImmersiveView': true,
    'useTabbedImmersiveView': true,
    'totalVideoCount':'0',
    'videoIngressATFSlateThumbURL':'',
    'mediaTypeCount':'0',
    'atfEnhancedHoverOverlay' : true,
    'winningAsin': 'B0033990ZQ',
    'weblabs' : {},
    'aibExp3Layout' : 1,
    'aibRuleName' : 'frank-powered',
    'acEnabled' : true,
    'dp60VideoPosition': 0,
    'dp60VariantList': '',
    'dp60VideoThumb': '',
    'dp60MainImage': 'https: //m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81zzDnLOXmL._AC_SY355_.jpg',
    'imageBlockRenderingStartTime': Date.now(),
    'shoppableSceneWeblabEnabled': false,
    
    'airyConfig' :A.$.parseJSON('{
            "jsUrl": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/vap/video/airy2/prod/2.0.1460.0/js/airy.skin._CB485981857_.js",
            "cssUrl": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/vap/video/airy2/prod/2.0.1460.0/css/beacon._CB485971591_.css",
            "swfUrl": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/vap/video/airy2/prod/2.0.1460.0/flash/AiryBasicRenderer._CB485925577_.swf",
            "foresterMetadataParams": {
                "marketplaceId": "ATVPDKIKX0DER",
                "method": "Sports.ImageBlock",
                "requestId": "CNWR29DQN7HDJNZBH41R",
                "session": "142-4118660-8915941",
                "client": "Dpx"
            }
        }')
    };
    A.trigger('P.AboveTheFold'); // trigger ATF event.
    return data;
});"""

# method 1
# note that this is NOT an r-string
index = re.search('"large": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41mHHkM79UL._AC_.jpg"', test_string)
print(index)

# method 2
# note that this is an r-string
index = re.search(r'"large": "https:\/\/m\.media-amazon\.com\/images\/I\/41mHHkM79UL\._AC_\.jpg"', test_string)
print(index)

# method 3
# without regex
print(test_string.find('"large": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41mHHkM79UL._AC_.jpg"'))
```

↑ scroll down, the relevant code is at the bottom of this block ↑

Running this code produces the following output:

```
<re.Match object; span=(331, 398), match='"large": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41m>
<re.Match object; span=(331, 398), match='"large": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41m>
331
```